# Include Xenforo Redactor iframe in Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, redactor, xenforo

I'm trying to create a Tampermonkey script for a website running Xenforo. Specifically I'm trying to target the WYSIWYG editor iframe and run the script when I edit the content but I just don't know how to do it.

If I target the website itself, the script doesn't run when editing the content in the iframe. The source code doesn't have a `src` tag, and if I check the Chrome inspector the frame in question is on `about:blank`

Comment: It's a same-origin frame which you can access directly from the main page via its contentDocument property. I'd need the page URL to provide a more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I ended up getting the desired results using `waitForKeyElements` like this:

`waitForKeyElements (
    "body",
    r,
    false,
    ".redactor_textCtrl"
);
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, here's a more detailed explanation on how I got it to work.

In the userscript header, include `waitForKeyElements`:

`// @require https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js`

Then in the code section:

```
waitForKeyElements (
    'body',
    r,
    false,
    '.redactor_textCtrl'
);

function r(jNode) {
    'use strict';

    jNode[0].addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
       console.log(e);
    }, false);
}
```

This allowed me to act upon changes in the text editor.